# How to identify the default sender IP address?

Tags: marketing-cloud, deliverability

In context of IP warming, I wonder how (within Marketing Cloud interface) to identify which IP address emails are being sent from.

Comment: Thanks @Lukas for re-framing my question correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you purchased a dedicated IP, you can see it in the Deliver profile:

> When you create a delivery profile, you specify the IP address to use.
>   If you do not use a private domain, you select the account default.

Here’s the help doc: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_delivery_profiles.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

If you haven’t purchased your own IP, you’re on a shared one, and there is currently no way to check the IP address from the interface:

> By design, it is not currently possible to locate the default IP
>   address used for email sends in your Marketing Cloud account.
>
> For assistance obtaining your account's default IP email sending
>   address, please create a Case with Marketing Cloud Support via
>   Salesforce Help.

Help doc: [Find the default email sending IP address for your Marketing Cloud account](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000312745&language=en_US&mode=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&type=1)